# Proving partial sums $A_n = o(|z_k|^\rho)$, where $|z_k|\to\infty$ is increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

The following is a question in Lang's Complex Analysis, fourth edition, Chapter XIII $\S 4$, problem $5a$:

> Let $\{ a_k \} , \{ z_k \}$ be sequences of complex numbers such that $|z_k| \to \infty$ and $|z_k| \le |z_{k+1}|$.  Let $\rho > 0$ such that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|a_k|}{|z_k|^\rho} < \infty$$  Let $A_n$ denote the partial sums of $|a_k|$.  Prove that $A_n = o(|z_n|^\rho)$.

I am having difficulty proving the little-oh part of it.  It's very easy to prove $A_n = O(|z_n|^\rho)$, since

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{A_n}{|z_n|^\rho} \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|a_k|}{|z_k|^\rho} < \infty$$

However, it's not so clear why the limit should go to $0$.  My attempt so far has been to assume that the conclusion does not hold so that $A_n \ge \epsilon |z_n|^\rho$ for infinitely many $n$.  We can rewrite the sum as:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|a_k|}{|z_k|^\rho} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{|z_k|^\rho} - \frac{1}{|z_{k+1}|^\rho} \right) A_k \approx \epsilon \sum_{k} 1 - \left( \frac{|z_k|}{|z_{k+1}|}\right)^\rho$$

The last sum seems like it might diverge (although I have my own doubts) but I'm stuck at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c_k=|a_k|/|z_k|^\rho \text { and } b_k=|z_k|^\rho$

Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{b_n}\sum_{k=1}^n c_kb_k=0$$

**Why the $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{b_n}\sum_{k=1}^n c_kb_k=0$:**

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of complex numbers such that $\sum a_n$ converges. Let $b_n$ be a sequence of real numbers which is increasing, i.e., $b_n \le b_{n+1}$ for all $n$, and $b_n\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$

Given $\epsilon>0$, if we select a positive integer $n_0$ such that for all $m>n_0$ we have $\left|\sum_{n=n_0+1}^m a_n\right|<\epsilon$ and $b_{n_0}\ge0$. Then for $N>n_0$ splitting the sum we obtain:

$$\left|\frac{1}{b_N}\sum_{n=1}^N a_nb_n\right|\le\left|\frac{1}{b_N}\sum_{n=1}^{n_0} a_nb_n\right|+\left|\frac{1}{b_N}\sum_{n=n_0+1}^N a_nb_n\right|$$

The first sum will be $\le\epsilon$ for all large N. For the second sum we use summation by parts to obtain, after some elementary computations,

$$\sum_{n=n_0+1}^N a_nb_n=b_N(A_N-A_{n_0})-\sum_{k=n_0+1}^{N-1} (A_k-A_{n_0})(b_{k+1}-b_k)$$

where $A_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ are the partial sums. Therefore by the triangle inequality the fact that $\left|A_k-A_{n_0}\right|<\epsilon$ for all $k\ge n_0$ and that $b_k$ increases we get:

$$\left|\sum_{n=n_0+1}^N a_nb_n\right|\le\left| b_N\right|\epsilon+\epsilon(b_N-b_{n_0})$$

Hence for all large $N$ we have:

$$\left|\frac{1}{b_N}\sum_{n=n_0+1}^N a_nb_n\right|\le 3\epsilon$$

which concludes our proof.

However if we only assume that the partial sums of $\sum a_n$ are bounded, we cannot conclude that the limit is $0$.

Comment: I do want this result, but I want to know how to prove it.

Comment: @AndrewSalmon Okay I see. Let me try. Give me a few mins.

Comment: @AndrewSalmon I think I figured it out.

Comment: How do we conclude that $|A_k - A_{n_0}| < \epsilon$ when we chose $n_0$ according to the sequence $b_n$ and not $a_n$?

Comment: $\left|A_k-A_{n_0}\right|<\epsilon$ by the triangle inequality. See: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleInequality.html

Comment: How are we justified in applying the triangle inequality?  If you mean that $A_k$ converges, and you're applying a convergence argument, how do we know that $n_0$ is large enough?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23594/discussion-between-andrew-salmon-and-yagna-patel).

Comment: Wait a minute, I see it now!  OK, so we define $n_0$ by splitting $\sum a_n$, for some reason, I missed that the first time around.